# Laurent Expansion of $\frac{1}{z(z-i)^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

How can we compute the Laurent expansion of

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z-i)^2}$$

about $0$ in $\Omega=B_1(0)\setminus\{0 \}$?

Thoughts:

By partial fractions we have that

$$f(z)=\frac{1}{z-i}-\frac{i}{(z-i)^2}-\frac{1}{z}$$

but I'm unsure is to which expansions will be valid in $\Omega$. Any help would be very appreciated.

Best, MM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's a trick:
$$
\frac{1}{z-i}=\frac{i}{1-z/i}=i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(z/i)^n
$$
also,
$$
\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{z-i}=\frac{-1}{(z-i)^2}
$$
so that
$$
\frac{-i}{(z-i)^2}=i\frac{d}{dz}\frac{1}{z-i}=i\frac{d}{dz}i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(z/i)^n=-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} nz^{n-1}(-i)^n
$$
you can piece it together from there

Comment: Many thanks! Exactly what I was looking for.